# Get JSON variable into webpage

Tags: php, json, web, html

I have started to learn JSON with PHP. First I wan't to learn, how to create some easy API which will get some data from database from main server and use it in other webpage. I have found some solutions which will get these data into web browser console and not just specific data I need for that web but all data from database.

For example:

**DATABASE**

id: 1
name: test
status: active

id: 2
name: test2
status: disable

**INTO TEST.COM WEB**

It get just record whos name is TEST and use its status.

```
$status = RECORD FROM DATABASE;
if ($status == 'disable') { 
  echo 'THIS WEBPAGE STATUS IS DISABLE';
} else { 
  echo 'THIS WEBPAGE STATUS IS ACTIVE';
}
```

Could some one help me with this, please? It looks very east from what I have seen, but just not for me, because I am new with this JSON.

Thanks a lot

Comment: What exactly do you need help with? I.e. are you getting the wrong result? What do you think it ought to be?

Comment: In API response what exactly you need to show and you want to manage the response using javascript?

Comment: You should take a look at PHP `json_encode()` and jQuery AJAX, then provide a more specific question on what you need help with.

Answer (score 1):

Simply use json_enconde() as @Siphon said.

If that doesnt work try to do this:

```
<?php
   echo "<pre>";
   print_r($status);
   echo "</pre>";
?>
```

Check what that says, if something like this shows up:

```
$data = RECORD FROM DATABASE;



 Array $data(
        ['status'] => 'enabled',
    );
```

if that shows up then your if statment is wrong and you need to do this:

```
$data= RECORD FROM DATABASE;
if ($data['status'] == 'disable') { 
  echo 'THIS WEBPAGE STATUS IS DISABLE';
} else { 
  echo 'THIS WEBPAGE STATUS IS ACTIVE';
}
```

Comment: Thanks for that. But my problem isnt about making php code part, my problem is about making json code... 

I will try to write more about that..

I would like help with making that part which is on online server X where are json code and some php code, like DB with websites (Y, Z) and its status... and into these websites (Y, Z) I check if into server X website status is disable or active.

something like this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=F5pXxS0y4bg but just with results for one website not all and dont show these results into consule but use it in website functions.

Comment: If you give me your email i can help you.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is broad but here are some pointers:

you will need a query

```
SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE name = ?
```

Then you encode the data (array) to `PDO` using `json_encode()`

Example in PDO:

```
$data = $stmt->fetchAll();
$json = json_encode($data);
```